# lualatex bug confuses latexmk dependency tracking

Tags: luatex, latexmk

> The described issue has been confirmed as a bug in `luatex` that can be expected to be solved in TeXLive 2018. Also  `latexmk` itself has been extended to deal with this issue in version 4.55d.

For a large deck of lecture slides I am refactoring my custom Makefile into a more streamlined solution based on `latexmk` with the `-use-make` option.

While this works fine with `pdflatex` as engine, it causes lot's of `make` invocations with `lualatex` for targets that are actually part of the texmf tree. Minimal example:

```
% slides.tex
\RequirePackage{luatex85} 
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{A Frame}
    Some content
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this with

```
latexmk -lualatex -norc -use-make slides.tex
```

(`-norc` to make sure no hidden options are passed to `latexmk`)

Compilation works, but I get the following:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017, version: 4.52c.
Latexmk: 'lualatex': source file 'beamericonarticle.20.pdf' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "beamericonarticle.20.pdf"'
------------
make: *** No rule to make target `beamericonarticle.20.pdf'.  Stop.
Latexmk: 'lualatex': source file 'beamericonarticle.pdf' doesn't exist. I'll try making it...
------------
Running 'make "beamericonarticle.pdf"'
------------
make: *** No rule to make target `beamericonarticle.pdf'.  Stop.
<... and so on ..,>
Latexmk: All targets (slides.pdf) are up-to-date
```

I assume the culprit comes from the fact, that `lualatex` behaves slightly different to `pdflatex` with respect to the `-recorder` option, which is (AFAIK) employed by `latexmk` for input dependency tracking. In the `lualatex` version we find one extra line in the generated `slides.fls` file for every included image:

```
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/beamer/art/beamericonarticle.pdf
INPUT beamericonarticle.pdf      <-- not generated by pdflatex!
INPUT /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/beamer/art/beamericonarticle.20.pdf
INPUT beamericonarticle.20.pdf   <-- not generated by pdflatex!
```

So apparently, `latexmk` does not know what to make out of these "extra" INPUTs and, thus, calls `make` to build them.

**Employed Versions:**

`This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/MacPorts 2017_2)`

`Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017. Version 4.52c`

**Questions:**

- Is this a bug or a feature of `lualatex`?
- Or maybe the lua-specific part of the graphics driver is to blame here?
- Possible workarounds?

Comment: I don't get the short version `INPUT beamericonarticle.pdf` with miktex, only with texlive (2017 and 2018). So I think it should be reported on the texlive mailing list, I will do it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. This also has reminded me to always include version information.

Comment: This has been corrected in the luatex sources. So it should be okay in tl18.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are adventurous enough to fiddle around with the (amazingly well documented!) `latexmk` source code, I have a quick workaround:

The following lines should be **inserted** in `parse_fls` function definition (`sub parse_fls`):

```
4588         elsif (/^\s*INPUT\s+([^\/]*)$/) {
4589           # Ignore entries without any directory part
4590           # Those are additionally inserted in some versions of lualatex
4591           # see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420274
4592           next;
4593         }
```

Note that the line numbers will vary, depending on the precise version of `latexmk`. They should be inserted **before the following existing** lines:

```
4594         elsif (/^\s*INPUT\s+(.*)$/) {
4595             # Take precautions against aliasing of foo, ./foo and other possibilities for cwd.
```

Comment: I've put an improved improvement in  v. 4.55b of `latexmk` at http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html  In this version, `latexmk` tests whether the name in a INPUT line of the fls file corresponds to an actual file.  If the file doesn't exist, `latexmk` doesn't consider the file as a dependency and types out a prominent warning message.

Comment: @JohnCollins:  How would that interact with the `-use-make` option, which, AFAIU is supposed to invoke `make` for nonexistent dependencies?

Comment: It will make the interaction with `-use-make` better. Dependency information is from both the .fls and .log files. If a file is reported in the .fls file but `latexmk` finds it doesn't exist, then either it's because of a bug (as in lualatex) or because the file got deleted (as with temporary files in the minted package). In either case, it is not a true dependency.  But missing files deduced from the .log file are correctly potential dependencies for which `make` could be used.  The new `latexmk` hasn't changed its behavior for those.

Comment: @JohnCollins: Thanks, I can confirm that 4.55d works well around the issue! However, I found a (probably) related one with `lualatex` and the output file: If I add `-output-directory=./build` to the command line in the question, `latexmk` always warns  `Latexmk: ===For rule 'lualatex', actual output 'slides.pdf' appears not to match expected output './build/slides.pdf'`. Again this does not happen with `pdflatex` as engine.

Comment: You can safely ignore the warning message about the output filenames from `lualatex` not matching. This is caused by an annoying quirk of `lualatex` compared with the other engines.  It doesn't affect the functioning of `latexmk`, so I plan to change `latexmk` so that it won't produce a warning in this case.  (There are other cases where a warning could be useful, but this isn't one of them.)